# How do you design a microservice with both external API and internal API?

Tags: microservices

Imagine an OrderService, most of its APIs are exposed through an API gateway and are protected by JWT token. But there are a few APIs I want to be called only internally by other microservices. Depending on the scenario, by the time these internal APIs are called, the user might not have logged in; thus there is no token to pass in the first place. (For example, an AggregateService or RecommendationService asks for the orders of last week)

Before I try to cook something all by myself, I want to ask if there are some established ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You secure the internal communication using a service account with a token or key or something that is passed as a secret during startup (as opposed to logging in).

In fact, such a service shouldn't expose an API to an external services at all, all communication runs via the service accounts. The gateway or some other service needs to manage the user login and translate it into some system-specific user information which is then passed as domain information (rather than in an actual authorization mechanism).

So the workflow is

1. User logs into gateway and requests data
2. gateway authenticates user, creates an internal user object
3. gateway routes request to relevant internal service, authorizing with the service account and passing the created user object in the request
4. service checks which data is relevant to the given user object and returns it to the gateway
5. gateway returns information to the user.

It's kind of similar to how you don't give user actual database user accounts.

Comment: Interesting. Now I realized that I was working in the wrong direction.  I coupled my microservices with the knowledge that requests come from different sources, with which they should be agnostic. That's why I felt so awkward to work on the problem.